# how to send http response using stream

Tags: dart, data-stream, dart-async

I would like to have simple API in my http server so everytime I write to HttpResponse I use stream.

so I convert all object into stream, ie object->json->stream

```dart
Stream<List<int>> toStream(Object value) {
    var json = JSON.encode(value);
    var controller = new StreamController<List<int>>(onListen: () => UTF8.encode(json));
    return controller.stream;
}
```

and later

```dart
(response as HttpResponse).addStream(toStream({"a": 1, "B": 2})
.then(() => response.flush())
.catchError((e, stack) {
    _logger.error("Handling ${context.path} finished with an error: $e");
    _logger.debug(stack.toString());
})
.whenComplete(() => response.close());
```

but I get error

```dart
Uncaught Error: Bad state: StreamSink is bound to a stream
Stack Trace: 
#0      _StreamSinkImpl.close (io_sink.dart:122)
#1      _HttpOutboundMessage.close (http_impl.dart:481)
```

Im not sure what I am doing wrong here. I saw examples where File's input stream was piped to response but I cannot make it work either.

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things to note here:

First, the JSON and UTF8 encoders will produce a single value when you're calling `encode()`, so you'll be creating a Stream of just a single value. I wonder how much value you get from that.

Second, your Stream doesn't actually get any values. `onListen` is called when the first listener subscribes, but any value returned from `onListen` isn't used for anything. To create a Stream from a single value you probably want to use `new Stream.fromIterable()`:

```dart
<List<int>> toStream(Object value) =>
    new Stream.fromIterable([UTF8.encode(JSON.encode(value))])
```

So that should cause a value to actually get into the Stream, and take care of your error. I think the source of you error is that the input stream is not closed, and creating it from an Iterable will close the Stream when the Iterable is exhausted.

`pipe()` should also now work, so you can try this:

```dart
toStream({"a": 1, "B": 2}).pipe(response)
  .then((_) {
    print("done");
  });
```

All said though, I don't see how this is better than:

```dart
response
  ..write(JSON.encode(value))
  ..close();
```

Comment: well of course, but having simple API that always return Stream is nicer if you want add files and other stuff that actually can produce data in chunks. If I work on stream I can transform it (ie. Gzip) in other part of server, am I wrong?

for example I have a use case where I send large JSON object like 70MB! crazy :)

Comment: And you right, I somehow missed pretty important thing to use controller.add(UTF8.encode(json)); controller.close(); as described here https://www.dartlang.org/articles/creating-streams/

Answer (score 0):

Try this example POST Request for json application with Streaming response:

**POST Request** here :

```dart
request = http.Request('POST', url);
request.headers.addAll({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  request.body = jsonEncode({'code': 'aQDZl8cp'});
```

**StreamingResponse** here:

```dart
 var streamedResponse = await request.send();
streamedResponse.stream.listen((List<int> chunk) {
//Todo
}
```

Full code:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  var url = Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:5000/download_file/');

  var request = http.Request('POST', url);
  request.headers.addAll({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  request.body = jsonEncode({'code': 'aQDZl8cp'});

  var streamedResponse = await request.send();

  int totalBytes =
      int.tryParse(streamedResponse.headers['content-length'] ?? '') ?? 0;
  int downloadedBytes = 0;

 streamedResponse.stream.listen((List<int> chunk) {
    downloadedBytes += chunk.length;
    double progress = downloadedBytes / totalBytes * 100;
    print('Progression: ${progress.toStringAsFixed(2)}%');
  });
}
```